# Block web from show notify app badge in taskbar, Electronjs

Tags: javascript, webview, notifications, electron

[taskbar icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTsMT.png)

I have this issue when i use telegram with the webview inside my Electron js app, telegram show notify of new chat message, then a badge number show in taskbar (check the image above)

How to block this behavior of the webview ? maybe remove some permission access ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.